# SSIS Data Flow Resulting in Suspended SPIDs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've an SSIS package with the following design:

1. There're 20 data flow tasks in a package that read data from the same table and load to  20 different tables.
2. MaxConcurrentExecutable is set to 6, so it executes 6 tasks in parallel.
3. There is a single connection manager for all source components with RetainSameConnection is set to true.
4. There are 20 additional connection managers used by each respective destination.
5. Source and destination are on the same SQL Server database. SSIS runs on a separate server. Both database and SSIS servers are 4cpu and 8gb ram.

This is running very slowly. 
When I see sp_who2, I notice the select queries (spids) that read from the source are suspended sometimes blocked by themselves, and spids that do bulk insert to destination are awaiting command.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening. Where do I need to look to optimize this (database performance, hardware, etc.,)?

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the wait type and wait resource in sys,dm_os_waiting_tasks? Is the package running 6 tasks, each of which then get parallelized? For example, if MaxDOP = 8, are you seeing it using 48 threads in sys.dm_exec_requests?

Comment: Robert - Sorry, it took longer to (learn) check those. Wait type for selects is CXPACKET, I don't see any waits for inserts but I don't all six of them all the time as running sessions. There are only 6, not 48 threads.

Comment: If your requirement is to read the same data 20 times for 20 different destinations can you change your flow to use a multicast transform? Have a single data source and multicast it into the different flows.

Comment: ... or if that does not work then what are your transaction settings? Can you set your reads to be non-transactional and use NOLOCK query hits?